# is it possible to use inheritance in uiautomator? if so how?

Tags: java, android, testing, android-testing, android-uiautomator

When I try to instantiate `testAYLogout()` and run the application, `testAXEndTrip()` also runs. Why is that?

```
public class ApplicationTest extends UiAutomatorTestCase {

    public void testAYLogout() throws RemoteException, UiObjectNotFoundException {
        //Get the device state
        UiDevice myDevice = getUiDevice();
        //menu button
        UiObject menuButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.ImageButton.class.getName()).index(0));
        //logout button
        UiObject logoutButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.CheckedTextView.class.getName()).text("Logout"));
        //yes button
        UiObject yesButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Button.class.getName()).text("Yes"));
        //no button
        UiObject noButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Button.class.getName()).text("No"));
        UiObject loginText = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()).text("Login"));

        if (!myDevice.isScreenOn()) {
            myDevice.wakeUp();
        }

        //click menu button and wait for new window
        menuButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
        assertTrue(logoutButton.exists());
        //click logout
        logoutButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
        //click no
        noButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
        menuButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
        logoutButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
        //click yes button
        yesButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
        assertTrue(loginText.exists());

    }

public void testAXEndTrip() throws RemoteException, UiObjectNotFoundException {


        //get device
        UiDevice myDevice = getUiDevice();
        //pick up location feild
        UiObject okButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Button.class.getName()).text("Ok").index(0));
        //end trip button
        UiObject endTripButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Button.class.getName()).text("END TRIP").index(1));
        //no button
        UiObject noButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Button.class.getName()).text("No"));
        //yes button
        UiObject yesButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Button.class.getName()).text("Yes"));
        //submit button
        UiObject submitButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Button.class.getName()).text("Submit"));
        //rate button
        UiObject rateButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.ImageButton.class.getName()).index(4));
        //feedback field
        UiObject feedback = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.EditText.class.getName()).index(1));
        //map
        UiObject map = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(android.view.View.class.getName()).index(0));

        //wake up device if screen is off
        if (!myDevice.isScreenOn())
            myDevice.wakeUp();

        rateButton.waitForExists(5000);
        rateButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
        feedback.setText("ride or die ma niguh");
        submitButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
        assertTrue(map.exists());

    }

}
```

Then this is my main class

```
public class MainTest extends ApplicationTest{

    public static void TestMain() throws RemoteException, UiObjectNotFoundException {
        MainTest login = new MainTest();
        login.testAYLogout();

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use [Testing Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator).

First add `uiautomator` dependency to your gradle file

```
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
}
```

Then, create a test case class like this one

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = 18)
public class MySampleTest extends MyAbstractTest {
   ...

   @Test
   public void myTest() {
       ...
   }

}
```

Finally, run your tests. Make sure to specify `AndroidJUnitRunner` as the default instrumentation runner in your project.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

Comment: i already did that sir and my application is running and is having no problems. but is it possible to use inheritance since android is java?

Comment: figured out where i did wrong thanks for the help guys.

Comment: It would be helpful for other people in your same situation to know what was the problem. If this is the solution please accept the answer to close it.